# Save Variables in the Variables-Pane of Pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

In Pycharm, is there any way we can easily save all the variables in the variables-pane during testing.

Appreciate for the insight

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to do this? See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Im looking for better alternative

Comment: Write tests instead of debugging?